# Debugging Typescript for Cordova App in Intellij

Tags: cordova, intellij-idea, typescript, ionic-framework, webstorm

I'm intending to write a new Cordova app with Typescript and Ionic in Intellij.

I currently develop using js and use the chrome remote debugging feature (to device) which allows me to step through the js code.

Is there currently a way to achieve remote debugging with the Typescript code as opposed to the transpiled js code from Intellij.

If this is not possible any suggestions for workflow would be appreciated.

TIA

**UPDATE:**

There is currently a JetBrains issue ~ [Add Cordova debugging support](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14781)

Hopefully, if implemented, this will address my question (above).

If you want this feature, vote on the link above.

Comment: Stronger typing, mo' problems.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but it is built in and working in Visual Studio and more or less in Chrome Dev tools.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but I can't help regarding remote debugging support for TypeScript in Intellij.

We use https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-support which provides source map support for stack traces which is really helpful in tracing the error to the actual location in the TypeScript file.

Comment: Thanks Param, I will take a look.